# Back titration of excess HCl used for dissolving limestone

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, stoichiometry, titration

> $15.0~\mathrm{mL}$ of $1.4~\mathrm{M}\ \ce{HCl}$ was mixed with $1.00~\mathrm{g}$ of limestone (impure $\ce{CaCO3}$) until all the solid had dissolved. The solution was then transferred to a conical flask and made up to $200~\mathrm{mL}$ with water. A $20.0~\mathrm{mL}$ portion was then neutralised by $8.50~\mathrm{mL}$ of a $0.1~\mathrm{M}\ \ce{NaOH}$ solution.
> Calculate:
>
> 1. Amount of excess $\ce{HCl}$ in the $20.0~\mathrm{mL}$ portion
> 2. Amount of excess $\ce{HCl}$ in the $200~\mathrm{mL}$ portion
> 3. Amount of $\ce{HCl}$ which reacted with $\ce{CaCO3}$

My attempt:

When the limestone is dissolved,

$$\ce{2 HCl(aq) + CaCO3(s) -> CaCl2(aq) + CO2(g) + H2O(l)}$$

$$n(\ce{HCl}) = c \times V = (15 \times 10^{-3}~\mathrm{L}) (1.4~\mathrm{M}) = 0.021~\mathrm{mol}$$
$$n(\ce{CaCO3}) = x~\mathrm{mol}$$

When the solution is diluted to $200~\mathrm{mL}$ the molarity of $\ce{HCl}$ can be found by,
\begin{align}
n_\mathrm i &= n_\mathrm f\\
c_\mathrm i V_\mathrm i &= c_\mathrm f V_\mathrm f\\
c_\mathrm f &= \frac{c_\mathrm i V_\mathrm i}{V_\mathrm f}\\
\therefore c_\mathrm f (\ce{HCl}) &= \frac{(15\times 10^{-3}~\mathrm{L})(1.4~\mathrm{M})}{(200\times 10^{-3}~\mathrm{L})} = 0.105~\mathrm{M}
\end{align}

I'm having doubts about my working up until this stage. Am I correct so far?

Answer (score 3):

It is generally a good idea to approach problems in the order that sub-questions are asked in. There is often a paedagogic reasoning in that order that can help you approach the answer.

In this case, the key point is that the limestone is *impure* $\ce{CaCO3}$, and that thus we do not know how much of the acid was initially neutralised with $\ce{CO2}$ evolution. Approaching the question from this side, as you did, is not very helpful, since we are missing an important value to calculate from.

What we *do* know, however, is the final end of the experiment: that $8.50~\mathrm{ml}$ of $0.1~\mathrm{M}\ \ce{NaOH}$ were able to neutralise a certain portion of the remaining hydrochloric acid. You should think of this as being a titration.

Once you have realised that, it makes sense why the first question asks for the amount of substance in the $20.0~\mathrm{ml}$ aliquot — it is the one you can actually calculate quickly, and it will lead you to the entire solution.

Thus, your plan of action is:

- find the concentration or amount of $\ce{HCl}$ in the $20.0~\mathrm{ml}$ portion by known formulae used for titration problems (your work so far shows you can do this);

> We have $\ce{HCl + NaOH -> NaCl + H2O}$, so
>  $$\begin{align} n_\ce{HCl} = n_\ce{NaOH} &= (\pu{8.50 mL})(\pu{0.1 M}) \\ &= \pu{0.00085 mol} \end{align}$$

- thencefrom calculate the concentration or amount of $\ce{HCl}$ in the entire $200~\mathrm{ml}$ sample from similar formulae;

> A $\pu{20 mL}$ portion of the $\ce{HCl}$ simply has one-tenth of the original amount of $\ce{HCl}$, so in the entire $\pu{200 mL}$, we have:
>  $$n_\ce{HCl} = (\pu{0.00085 mol}) \times \frac{\pu{200 mL}}{\pu{20 mL}} = \pu{0.0085 mol}$$

- Next, decide how much hydrochloric acid was lost in the dissolution of the limestone.

> At the start, we had a grand total of
>  $$\begin{align} n_{\ce{HCl},\mathrm{tot}} &= (\pu{15.0 mL})(\pu{1.4 M}) \\ &= \pu{0.021 mol} \end{align}$$
>  which you already calculated. After reacting with the limestone, we were left with only $\pu{0.0085 mol}$ of that. So, the amount that reacted is simply:
>  $$n_{\ce{HCl},\mathrm{reacted}} = \pu{0.021 mol} - \pu{0.0085 mol} = \pu{0.0125 mol}.$$